# Setting a background color for the body of an html doc

Tags: html

I have an html document which has a body with many `<p>`, each with their own style (see below). There is also 1 image in the document. I would like a red background to appear behind all the text and the image in the body. How can I do this please?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <br /><br />
 <p style="color:rgb(0,0,0);margin: 0px;font-family: Helvetica, Helvetica;font-size:20px;">
  <b>John Dow</b>
 </p>
 <p style="color:rgb(0,0,0);margin: 0px;font-family: Helvetica, Helvetica;font-size:20px;">
    123 Street
    Cape Town
    8005
 </p>
 <img style="border:none; margin: 8px 0px 0px 0px;" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/kruranimagestest/50CB6EA7-A5F8-43C7-A826-8DBD4DBC0DB1.jpg" alt="image">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: With many what? `body { background: red; }`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS to add a red background to the entire body or just the image a paragraph tags.

**Entire body:**

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background: red;
}
</style>
```

**<p> and <img> tags only:**

```
<style type="text/css">
p, img {
    background: red;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your whole website to be red, just adjust the body tag: `<body style="background-color:red;">...`. If you want to have a red background only behind the elements inside your body use the following style in your `<head>` instead:

```
<style>body > *{ background-color:red;}</style>
```

Note that you can simplify your code if you put your css rules into a global stylesheet:

```
body > p{
     color:rgb(0,0,0);
     margin: 0px;
     font-family: Helvetica, Helvetica;
     font-size:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to where you want:

```
background-color:red;
```

It can be added to the body element to have all the page colored or to any p element to color it only.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body style="background-color: #FF0000">
```

On a side note, is there reason why you are not using a CSS (.css) file?